# dredd fails to run with errors 'Data does not match any schemas from 'anyOf' and such more

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0, dredd

Trying to run dredd on swagger documentation.
Dredd fails with next errors:

```
- error: API description parser error in /albums.json:266 (from line 266 column 10 to column 21): Data does not match any schemas from 'anyOf'    
- error: API description parser error in /albums.json:266 (from line 266 column 10 to column 21): No enum match for: s
- error: API description parser error in /albums.json:266 (from line 266 column 10 to column 21): Expected type array but found type string
```

errors refers to this part of JSON:

```
265  "photos": { "$ref": "#/definitions/PhotoEntity" },
266  "created_at": {
267    "type": "s",
268    "format": "g",
269    "description": "Дата создания"
270  }
```

Full JSON available by [gist](https://gist.github.com/slim1979/28c029581d7a2f5accb251cf10fb9881).
Swagger-ui work with this JSON perfectly, manual testing passes, as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
"type": "s",
```

with

```
"type": "string",
```

There're also other errors in your API definition - use https://editor.swagger.io to check for syntax errors.

Comment: thanks, seems, like swagger documentation set wrong

Comment: you, maybe, can help me with types like _**symbol**_, _**text**_, which is also cause an error? if I can handle _**text**_ by myself - change it to _**string**_, I wonder, how to change _**symbol**_ type

Comment: @slim1979 Here's the list of OAS2 data types and predefined `format` values: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#data-types Pick the type that matches best.